# Does Ansible copy code on agents? How does it execute these commands?

Tags: ansible

As Chef copies your code to agents, does Ansible copy the code or does it just convert to commands and execute them?

I have checked lot of docs but did not find any good doc explaining this workflow.

Answer (score 2):

In short: *for each task* Ansible packs required modules and libs plus input data into tiny package, delivers to temporary location on target system (usually via ssh), executes it there and cleanup after itself.

Ansible doesn't copy your playbook as a whole to target system. Only data required for each individual task.

More details about workflow in developer guide [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html).

Answer (score 1):

For target machines running Unix/Linux, a control machine:

1. opens an SSH session to the target node, performs basic preparations (e.g. creates temporary directories);
2. creates customised scripts (mostly Python) and transfers them using SFTP (default) or SCP ([configurable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#scp-if-ssh)) to the target;
3. finally it executes the scripts on the target host.

The process is repeated for each single task on each single host (Ansible can also be optimised to leave an open SSH session for multiple tasks).

---

In Ansible, basic units of work are coded in [modules](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/modules_by_category.html) and specified in (called from) tasks.

- For most modules the logic is written in Python. Whether a specific module uses external programs or not, the actions to be performed are wrapped in Python scripts.
- One exception to the above is the [`raw` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/raw_module.html) which executes the specific command directly in SSH session.
- Another special case is the [`synchronize` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) which is executed on the control machine and uses `rsync` to transfer files.

---

Some modules, which target mostly [cloud](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_cloud_modules.html) services and [network](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_network_modules.html) devices, are executed on local host (or proxy machine) and access destination systems and devices with their APIs.

For Windows target machines, Ansible connects with WinRM and runs PowerShell scripts on the target machine through Windows-native PowerShell remoting feature.